# how to move from view to activity and back in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two classes A and B A is main activity class and B is View class. Now I am calling View by setcontentview. when the view is active and i am drawing on it . I want the activity class is active so how do i do that ?

```
public class A extends Activity {
    B b;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.button);
        b = new B(this);

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showView);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 setContentView(drawView);
                 drawView.requestFocus();
            }
        });

    }
}

public class b extends View  implements OnTouchListener {


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        mContext = context;
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);




    }
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        mCanvas = canvas;
draw something 
}


}
```

Comment: when the View is active i want to get back to the Activity view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setContentView()` replaces the entire view of the `Activity`.  If you want to go back to the old view, call `setContentView()` again with the old view again.  By convention though, this is bad.  Generally you only do one view per activity.